# Robotframework Taking screenshot failed

Tags: robotframework

Hello I am using robotframework on win10 PC trying to do screenshot using library "Screenshot"

But this keyword can't capture screenshot and showed a warning message:
[image: Warning message]

.robot file :

```
*** Settings ***     
Library    Screenshot
 
*** Test Cases ***  
Test01   
     Take Screenshot
```

Comment: Is there something in the warning message that you don't understand?

Comment: Please don't link to an image of the warning. Take the time to copy, paste, and format it properly.

Comment: Are you running this as a service on windows, or does this happen when running on your desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the [Screenshot library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html) to work you'll need to install [Pillow](http://python-pillow.org/). See the excerpt of the [Robot Framework 3.0.2 documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html):

> How screenshots are taken when using Python depends on the operating
>   system. On OSX screenshots are taken using the built-in screencapture
>   utility. On other operating systems you need to have one of the
>   following tools or Python modules installed. You can specify the
>   tool/module to use when importing the library. If no tool or module is
>   specified, the first one found will be used.
>
> wxPython :: http://wxpython.org :: Required also by RIDE so many Robot
>   Framework users already have this module installed.
>
> PyGTK :: http://pygtk.org :: This module is available by default on most Linux
>   distributions.
>
> Pillow :: https://python-pillow.github.io :: Only works
>   on Windows. Also the original PIL package is supported.
>
> Scrot :: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot :: Not used on Windows. Install
>   with apt-get install scrot or similar.

Using `pip install Pillow` the relevant modules are installed and the screenshot functionality will work again.

Comment: After installed Pillow, the screenshot library works, thanks you.